# How Burmester's theory converts rotary motion of the crank to linear movement?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I have been studying the mechanism of Klann's Mechanical spider and there it was written that by [Burmester's theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmester%27s_theory) it converts rotary motion of the crank to linear movement. I tried searching but how it is accomplished? What's the basic concept behind this theory?

Comment: What about the wikipedia page did you not understand? It seems like a smart application of geometry but there is little that is actual physics.